# JQuery onclick nav hide and show

Tags: jquery, hide, show

I was wondering how to code a onclick event for a jquery nav

when you click go

```
<a href="#go">Go</a>
```

it should look for the id in the href and `.show()` and `.hide()` the other items of the same class like class hide. Anyone show me the code?

Comment: @user1324780. Please read the rules on how to ask a question before posting

Comment: @DG3 Where can they find the rules?

Comment: @Gray http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask and other links related to it. I think for 'programming section', they should include a link to http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: The easiest way to do it is <a href="#" onclick="$('#example').show();" /> You don't even need to create a function for this :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll first need to add a class or (preferably) an ID to your anchor, like this:

```
<a id="clicker" href="#go">Go</a>
```

Not quite sure what you are asking, but here is what I think you mean. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#clicker').click(function() {
  //Grab the "href" attribute of the anchor
    var anchor = $(this).attr('href');

  //If you want to hide
    $(anchor).hide();

  //Uncomment if you want to show
    //$(anchor).show();
  });
});
```

This code is untested, but *should* work.

Based on your question, this is what I think you mean. ;)

Comment: You don't even need to create a function for this :-) Just use <a href="#" onclick="$('#example').show()" />

Comment: @ChayaCooper the code you provided works but it just shows the element #example, but if he wants to show one element and hide the others? Thats what I would like to do right now too. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This might be close to what you're asking for but to be sure we need some more details and samples of what you've tried:

HTML:

```
<a href="#go">Go</a>

<div id="go" style="display:none;">
   Div for Go
</div>
```

​
jQuery:

```
// the element with the href of "#go"
$("[href='#go']").click(function() {
   // obtain the href value
   var href = $(this).attr("href");

   // find the element with an ID of #go and hide/show it 
   $(href).toggle();
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZGz4g/